# Does SML have an analog to Python's range()?

Tags: python, range, sml

I'm looking for an SML function that takes a nonnegative integer and returns a list of all integers from 0 up to but not including the given value, analogous to range() in Python. Yes, I can (and have) written my own, but I'd prefer something built in that I don't need to copy and paste into every project I want to use it in. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
% Python code
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

(* SML code: my implementation; I'd prefer a built-in version *)
fun range x = 
    let fun helper current stop = 
        if current = stop 
        then nil 
        else current :: (helper (current + 1) stop)
    in helper 0 x
    end;

(* my code when run *)
- range 10;
val it = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] : int list
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is maybe not as readable, but...

```
- List.tabulate(10, fn x => x)
val it = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] : int list
```

Comment: Ooh, List.tabulate is pretty much what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
fun ranger 0 = [ 0 ]
  | ranger x = x :: range x-1 

fun range x = reverse (ranger x)
```

Comment: That's not well-typed. And if you fix it by replacing 0 with [0] and `::` with `@`, it's O(n^2) while the OP's solution is O(n).

Comment: It's also still not built into a standard library. :-P

Comment: @sepp2k: You're right (I hadn't taken account of singly-linked lists). I've changed this to an O(2n) version (assuming the syntax is right - I don't actually know, or have, ML).

Comment: The best way to write this function recursively would be to let the helper function take the partial result as an argument. This way the function will be tail-recursive and the result does not have to be reversed. Also the pedant in me wants to point out that O(2n) is the same thing as O(n).